# How to change the color of QGraphicsSvgItem in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicssvgitem

so i want to change the color of an QGraphicsSvgItem in a QGraphicsScene. I have this little code snippet:

```
from PyQt5 import (QtWidgets as qtw, QtCore as qtc, QtGui as qtg, QtSvg as qsvg)

class HitIcon(qsvg.QGraphicsSvgItem):

    def __init__(self, field):
        super(HitIcon, self).__init__('my.svg'))
        self.setScale(.3)
        self._brush = qtg.QBrush(qtc.Qt.red)
        self.update()

    def paint(self, painter=None, Style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.boundingRect(), self._brush)
```

This fills the complete boundingRect of the svgitem with the specified color.
I searched the documentation of QPainter to find a way to only fill the svg path but couldn't find anything.

i also tried the following:

```
painter.fillPath(self.clipPath(), self._brush)

painter.fillRect(self.clipPath(), self._brush)
```

Comment: show the my.svg

Comment: here is the svg file: https://thenounproject.com/term/warship/24635/ @eyllanesc

Comment: I can't access the icon because it asks me to login

Comment: the account is free. The icons are licensed, they are free to use, but i'm not sure about the copyright so i won't post them directly.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't want to give my data to get an image